# Type hinting on Python subclasses

Tags: python, type-hinting

The `List[Geometry]` type hint on the code below does not cause `self.items.append(line)` to complain because `line` is a `Line` which is subclass of `Geometry`.

The same type hint causes the `item.is_horizontal` on the last line to say `Unresolved attribute reference 'is_horizontal' for class 'Geometry'`.

I think this happens because the `is_horizontal` property exists only in one of the subclasses of `Geometry`.

What is the correct way to avoid this warning?

With `List[Union[Geometry, Line, Circle]]` the warning goes away, but I'm not sure this is the correct solution. Listing a set of classes is not like saying `<Geometry> and all subclasses`.

```py
class Geometry:
    is_circle = is_line = False

class Line(Geometry):
    is_line = True          # property on Geometry and subclasses
    is_horizontal = True    # property only on Line

class Circle(Geometry):
    is_circle = True        # property on Geometry and subclasses
    radius = 10             # property only on Line

class Geometries:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items: List[Geometry] = []

    def add_line(self, line: Line):
        self.items.append(line)

    def horizontal_lines(self):
        return [item for item in self.items if item.is_line and item.is_horizontal]
```

Comment: `is_line` and `is_circle` are both redundant. You can replace, e.g, `item.is_line` with `isinstance(item, Line)`.

Comment: `is_horizontal` and `radius` should both be *instance* attributes, not class attributes. Not all lines are horizontal, and not all circles have radius 10.

Comment: You specify `items -> List[Geometry]` so `item in items: item.is_horizontal` seems a valid warning. You mean `item.is_line and item.is_horizontal` should short-circuit the `is_horizontal` check?

Comment: A static typechecker cannot assume that `item.is_horizontal` will only be evaluated when `item` has a runtime type of `Line`. You said it was a `Geometry`, so it has to assume it might *not* be a `Line`. You can use `cast` to tell the type checker it's OK: `if item.is_line and cast(Line, item).is_horizontal`.

Comment: All the properties shown here are obviously wrong. This is a stub of the class, enough to show what I need to show for type hinting.

Answer (score 1):

Use an actual type check, with `isinstance`:

```
def horizontal_lines(self):
    return [item for item in self.items if isinstance(item, Line) and item.is_horizontal]
```

From a static typing perspective, there is no connection between an `is_line` attribute and whether or not an object is an instance of `Line`. There could be other subclasses of `Geometry` somewhere else in the program with `is_line = True` but no `is_horizontal`, or instances could have `is_line` set at the instance level.

Comment: You are telling me to change the code, not the type hinting. I have good reason in my real code not to use `isinstance`.
I would like to know if there is a generic way to do the same as `Union[A,B,C,...]` where `B`, `C` and `...` are subclasses of `A`

Comment: @stenci: Yup. If you want to use static type checking, you need to write code that is statically type-safe - that or throw `Any` and `cast` and `#type:ignore` all over the place, but then you'd only be pretending to type check your code.

Comment: Your comment is the answer to my question: you can't.
Well... restricting the type to all subclasses of a given class is not pretending to type check. It is not perfect, but there is a lot of value in it.
I want PyCharm to tell me "you can use Geometry or any subclass of it". It is not perfect, but it's better than `Any` or no type check at all.

Comment: Also, that union isn't type-safe either. The warning going away when you use the union might be a bug in your IDE's type checker. [mypy correctly reports the error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=c5e2a6815e8dd8f5f27e11c5c2eec16f) as long as you annotate the method - by default, mypy doesn't check unannotated functions.

Comment: I am not trying to make type safe code. I'm trying to get the most out of type warnings, autocompletion and documentation, which in this case it means making sure that I'm using subclasses of a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Since `items` has a static type of `List[Geometry]`, the type checker cannot make any assumptions about what attributes a list element has beyond what is statically defined in `Geometry`. Since `is_horizontal` is not an attribute of *all* instances of `Geometry`, an access like `item.is_horizontal` is forbidden.

However, you can *assert* that `item` is really a `Line` based on runtime knowledge using `cast`. `cast(Line, item)` is a no-op at runtime, but the type checker treats it as meaning "whatever type `item` is, `cast` will return an instance of `Line`.

Given some more realistic definitions of `Geometry`, `Line`, and `Circle`,

```
from typing import cast, List


class Geometry:
    ...


class Line(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, slope, y_intercept):
        ...

    @property
    def is_horizontal(self):
        return self.slope == 0

    ...


class Circle(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, radius, center):
        self.radius = radius
        self.center = center

    ...
```

you can define `Geometries` (and in particular, `Geometries.horizontal_lines`) like so:

```
class Geometries:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items: List[Geometry] = []

    def add_line(self, line: Line):
        self.items.append(line)

    def horizontal_lines(self) -> List[Line]:
        return [item for item in self.items
                     if isinstance(item, Line) 
                        and cast(Line, item).is_horizontal]
```

Various static type-checkers *may* make the call to `cast` optional. For example, they could infer that given `isinstance(x, y) and z`, if `isinstance` returns True then the static type of `x` can be assumed to be `y` in `z`, regardless of any previous type hints regarding the static type of `x`. (If it were to return `False`, then `z` is dead code and needn't be checked at all.)

Comment: The cast isn't necessary after the `isinstance` check - mypy automatically uses the narrowed type.

Comment: Although since the OP seems to be using something other than mypy - mypy would have given different output - maybe they do need the cast.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm taking the view the `cast` is necessary in general, though any particular type checker might have hard-coded optimizations like recognizing what it would mean for `isinstance` to return True in this context.